# Share Session between Play framework and Django

Tags: java, python, django, single-sign-on, playframework

How can I create a single sign on application that will let me move from one section of my site to another. One section of my site uses play framework and the other is on django. My SSO know-how is very limited so be nice to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as stated by mandubian the best option is to have a central service that provides authentication tokens that all applications recognize and use to authenticate the user. And example of such a service is [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas), if as you say you are not experienced with SSO I would read about it to get the grasp of how it should work.

Just a warning: authentication and authorization is a critical part of an application, even more of a web application. I would advise against implementing your own solution, you will probably end up hacked and with problems (unless the apps are inside an intranet, the risks exist but are more forgiving usually). Try to use an existing solution like [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) or [JOSSO](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/JOSSO+-+Java+Open+Single+Sign-On+Project+Home)

Comment: More likely you will be hacked while using open-source solution for authentication and authorization. No one will spend time hacking one website while there are thousands and millions of websites working on the same open-source codebase unless you attract special attention.

Comment: @vladimirPrudnikov on the other hand as they are prone to be attacked they are getting security updates more often. Your own solution may be weak and you may never know it until it's too late

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be to use a cookie on your domain that can be read by both Play! and Django. The cookie could hold a temporary token that both apps can check at e.g. a shared DB in case the user is not already logged-in for that app.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a standard SSO mechanism, it should be managed by the mechanism itself...
The webserver (Django or Play) should redirect the user to the authentication page of the SSO server. The SSO server generates a token and sent it back to the client (in a cookie for example) and redirects the client to the webserver (Django or Play) which can itself validate the authentication with the SSO server using the given token. This token is then used between the client and the web servers until the end of authentication session.
So as arjan explained, you should share this token in a cookie for example and both web servers (django and play) should be able to manage it.